# bind german mutated vowel keys to functions

Tags: key-bindings, isearch

I have a German keyboard and would like to bind Isearch to `C-ö`.

How can I do this?

Comment: `isearch-forward` is bound to `C-s`. Why on earth would you bind it to `C-ö`??? The binding would be `(global-set-key (kbd "C-ö") #'isearch-forward)`.

Comment: @Tobias: Please consider moving your answer to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`isearch-forward` is bound to <kbd>C-s</kbd>.

Why on earth would you bind it to <kbd>C-ö</kbd>?
**EDIT:** See [Carsten D's interesting answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52087/bind-german-mutated-vowel-keys-to-functions/52091?noredirect=1#comment80376_52091) to this question in the comments.

The binding would be:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-ö") #'isearch-forward)
```

---

I keep the following info for others who stumple over this answer:

If you consider binding <kbd>C-s</kbd> to `save-buffer` to get closer to the key bindings of standard Windows applications I would like to make you aware of following modes:

- [`cua-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html) (can be turned on in the Options menu)
- [`ergoemacs-mode`](https://ergoemacs.github.io/) can be installed via `package-install` if [melpa](https://melpa.org/#/) is configured in `package-archives`.

Comment: thank you, and no worries, I want to keep the original emacs bindings, except for C-s since I find it hart to press with only my left hand. Having caps-lock as ctrl allos me to search with C-ö while keeping my fingers completely on the homerow